# How to generate a random values periodically and publish it using MQTT protocol?

Tags: javascript, node.js, random, mqtt

I want to repletely generate different random values for every 1 second and publish it to MQTT protocol.
The code is working but it is keep sending the last value how to make it that it will send a different value every 1 second?

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')

var Broker_URL = 'mqtt://localhost';
var client  = mqtt.connect(Broker_URL);

var MIN_PER_RANK =75
var MAX_PER_RANK =100

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("MQTT connected  "+ client.connected);
})

class virtualsensor {
    
    sendStateUpdate (newdata) {
        client.publish("testtopic", newdata)
    }
}

let vs = new virtualsensor()

let newdata = '';

for (var i=0; i<5; i++){
    newdata= String(Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX_PER_RANK - MIN_PER_RANK  + 1) + MIN_PER_RANK));
    vs.sendStateUpdate(newdata)
}

var interval = setInterval(function(){vs.sendStateUpdate(newdata)},1000);
```

the output:

```
testtopic 81
testtopic 76
testtopic 89
testtopic 100
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
testtopic 96
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop only generates 5 values, then the `setInterval()` just reuses the last value from that loop again.

The for loop isn't really doing anything useful here, it will publish the 5 "random" values in under a second (Which is not what you asked for) then the `setInterval()` just repeats the sending the last value over and over.

Remove the for loop and move the random value generator to the function passed to `setInterval()`

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  newdata= String(Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX_PER_RANK - MIN_PER_RANK  + 1) + MIN_PER_RANK));
  vs.sendStateUpdate(newdata)
},1000);
```